# I want to create a uniqueID for cutomers when they signup my webapp

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm creating a signup page for my web app using Django and I would like to create a unique ID for customers when they signup in sequential order.
ex:

```
first customer ID= 5000001
second customer ID= 5000002 
...
```

I don't want the customer `ID` visible to the users. The customer `ID` just for my purpose to create one to many relations to connect with their details in the database.

It would be really helpful if I can get some good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it could be override the "save" method of the model and add the field user_id to your user model :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):   
    if not self.pk:        
        last = get_the_last_id()            
        self.user_id = last+1                
    super(YourUserModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable and easier to let that happen on the database side,
In other words, alter the sequence that is responsible for generating new ids,
for your table.

1 ) This query will show you all `auto_increment` fields in your database.

```
select table_name, column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where extra like '%auto_increment%' 
and table_schema='YOUR_APP_DB_NAME';
```

The result should look like this

```
+---------------------------------------------+-------------+
| table_name                                  | column_name |
+---------------------------------------------+-------------+
| appname_tablename                           | id          |
....
```

2 ) once you decided which one you should reset its auto-increment start value,
for instance `appname_tablename_id`,

the query to reset its value is the following

```
ALTER SEQUENCE appname_tablename_id_seq RESTART WITH 5000001;
```

3 ) Now create an empty migration for that specific app

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name --empty
```

4 ) Inside that migration's operations array write this operation

```
migrations.RunSQL('ALTER SEQUENCE appname_tablename_id_seq RESTART WITH 5000001;')
```

and then run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

5 ) Now it will work as it should.